# Gatsby: how to pass data to React Context at build time

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have a **Gatsby site where I'm using React Context to provide a theme (heading, footer, styling, etc.) Now I want to add last build time to the footer**, e.g. "Last updated: 13 Nov 23:08". How can I do this?

Obviously, if I just put the buildTime inside the Context Provider or anywhere within the React Component that creates it, then the time will update with every refresh (as opposed to every build).

I figured I should be able to set `buildTime = new Date()` in `gatsby-node.js` createPages API, and then pass the buildTime in pageContext. But after passing it down a couple React components I end up needing to pass it to `<ThemeContext.Consumer>`. I can't pass props to the Context Consumer.

The best solution I've come up with is writing build time to a file and then loading that information from a file, which is obviously horrible, so it would be nice if there was a better solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use GraphQL to fetch build time in the Component which needs it (rather than passing it down through context provider). The StaticQuery below is executed at build time only.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby'

const IndexPage = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(query)

  return (
    <>
      <p>This site was last built on:</p>
      <p>{data.site.buildTime}</p>
    </>
  )
}

export default IndexPage

const query = graphql`
  query Info {
    site {
      buildTime(formatString: "DD/MM/YYYY")
    }
  }
`
```

From https://www.lekoarts.de/en/blog/tips-and-tricks-for-gatsby#date-of-last-build